# SIM phone DTMF Signal Frequency Problem

Tags: stm32

Is there a DTMF signal detection method in the smartphone [SIM] call?ex) keypad value or signal value [not frequency signal]

If you press the keypad button while you're on the phone with two iPhones, you don't hear the signal. So does the SAMSUNG phone.Please let me know how to detect DTMF signals after installing the aduino SIM.

Quectel EC25

Comment: And the manual says what?

Comment: The SIM telephone [smartphone NO] operates with the program and many telephones are automatically dialed and the voice guidance is given. Here, guide is heard and client presses the consultation -1 denial -2 number.I call my smartphone, so I need to read the DTMF signal from the received smartphone. The latest smartphone seems to be unable to read the signal.

Comment: Yes, we know what DTMF is and what it's used for. What does the manual for the Quetcel EC25 say about receiving DTMF tones?

Comment: I bought a product that used this component. I need to call, voice, and read the DTMF signal. I read the signal on the wired phone.How do we solve this?

Comment: The signal of the received Smart phone has to be read.

Comment: you are not answering the question that @Majenko is asking ... it is irrelevant why you want to detect the DTMF signal

Comment: @jsotola I have given up asking. I *think* he's saying it works when he uses a landline but doesn't when he uses his smartphone.

Comment: I suspect that because you're going mobile-to-mobile it's assuming it should use rfc2833  and not DTMF.

Comment: A way to get the keypad number if you press your keypad. Phone on mobile

Comment: We need to get the ivr [DTMF] signal from our customer's smartphone. It's a problem because we don't get it now. How?

Comment: How can you read the mobile touch tone?